# Messed up configuration by uninstalling PhpMyAdmin

Tags: server, apache2, uninstall, configuration, phpmyadmin

I uninstalled PhpMyAdmin by using `sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin`.
When phpmyadmin was deleted, the webserver couldn't start.
I get the following error:

```
    Started apache2
    apache2: Syntax error on line 219 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open
configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf: No such file or directory
```

I don't know how to solve this. I'm afraid phpmyadmin has messed up some things and tainted several configuration files.
I tried to edit the content of the `apache2.conf` but I dont find anything that has to do with phpmyadmin.

Comment: What is the line 219 referenced in the error message?

Comment: That file hasn't even got 219 lines. But I really get the feeling it has something to do with symbolic links. It's looking for a file that shows up in the terminal when I list files. But when I want to load that file (using PHP to test) it says it doesn't exist.

Comment: the file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` should be have line 219. Please add that line to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read your post again. Just remove the symbolic link: `sudo rm /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf`.

---

Edit: `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` doesn't have line 219 (for this case) because the complete file which the Apache2 server uses is consisted of the main content of the file and the content of all `.conf` files, involved with directives like: `IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf`.

---

Check for additional `phpmyadmin.conf` file in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/`.
If it is there, I think you must do:

```
sudo a2disconf phpmyadmin
sudo rm /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
```

or (which is the same):

```
sudo rm /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo rm /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
```

Comment: The file you name isn't there. Could it be something with symbolic links?

Comment: Is there `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf`?

Comment: No /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf isn't there.

Comment: I have read your post again. What is the result of `ls -la /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`? It looks like there is a broken symbolic link.

Comment: `total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Oct  3 21:12 ./
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root 4096 Oct  3 21:12 ../
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   35 Jun  9 08:31 000-default.conf -> ../sites-available/000-default.conf
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   34 Jul  1 10:53 001-cloud9.conf -> ../sites-available/001-cloud9.conf
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   27 Oct  3 21:12 phpmyadmin.conf -> /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` Readable: http://shorttext.com/826db5b0

Comment: Just remove the symbolic link: `sudo rm /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf`.

Comment: I will update my comment.